# Inserted SD-card not showing up on MacBook Pro, can't find or see it anywhere

Tags: sd-card

I inserted an SD card from a dashcam because it was full. The first time I inserted the card, it showed up and I deleted all the files on it. I went to plug it back in the dashcam and it still showed "storage full". I plugged it back into my Mac and it will not show up anymore. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Where did you look? The Finder and/or Disk Utility? What does the command `diskutil list` show? How about the Storage tab in the `About this Mac` popup window? Does the SD card appear in the System Information application window?

Comment: i checked these areas and nothing shows. The first time i plugged it in, i saw it right away in the finder.

Answer (score 1):

This may vary by dash cam.  With my dash cam, you must not delete files on the SD card using Finder or some other operating system utility.

The dash cam is intended to manage its own storage and, by itself, will remove old video when full keeping just the most recent.

If there is a need to reinitialise the SD card, this has to be done with the utility provided for the dash cam.

In your case, I think you have corrupted the storage and need to reinitialise the SD card in the way required by the dash cam.

Comment: honestly im not even sure what reinitialise means. the dash cam had a pop up on the screen and constantly said "storage full" so i assumed it wasnt recording anymore.

Comment: @JonPrusheik You are going to have to tell us the make and model of the dash cam. My dash cam has vendor provided software which maintains the data on the SD card and can, if required, initialise the card with the folders and files needed for recording in the dash cam.

Answer (score -1):

I think that with a normal erase using the delete button, the data doesn't actually erase the data, it just pretends that the data has been erased. This also enables you to undo the accidentally deleted files.

I think you need to format your media in Disk Utility.

Comment: how do i format? i cannot even find it in disk utility.

Comment: Also, how do you undo an erase, and, more specifically, how does this answer the question asked?

Comment: @JonPrusheik @nohillside You will not have the data correctly either, if you press `CMD` + `Z` while accidentally deleting it, you will be restored.  You need to press Show All Devices in Disk Utility (or in the Terminal `diskutil list external`  enter) and try to format it or press `S.O.S`. if the file system has been damaged. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210898